# Entring same text to all textboxes while writing in one textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox

How can I have the same text being entered in a text box to some other textboxes? I mean when I am typing in a textbox, the same string should go inside other textboxes on the fly!

Which event should be used in this case?

Comment: Have you tried looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextChanged event.

```
private void currencyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textbox1.Text = currencyTextBox.Text;
  textbox2.Text = currencyTextBox.Text;
  textbox3.Text = currencyTextBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Im a noob in WPF/winforms but in "currencyTextBox.Text", "currencyTextBox" is linked to your function name ?

Comment: No. it is name of the control of the TextBox which changes are to be detected and handled.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TextChanged` event. This event raises whenever there is a change in content of `TextBox`. You will have to handle it in all the `textboxes`. If there is any change in one copy this change to all but it is an ugly solution.

Also take a look at how `Bindings` work. It will be a much cleaner solution. Bind all the textboxes to a single `variable`. When the value in one `textbox` will change the associated `variable` will change and hence value in all the `textboxes` will change

Answer (score 0):

Use the [TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx)